# How to change the canvas linewidth with html range input (slider)?

Tags: javascript, canvas, input, slider, html5-canvas

I'm making a simple drawing canvas. I want to change the thickness of the brush(linewidth) dynamically via moving the slider. The problem is the linewidth value does change correspondingly with the slider. The initial value of the slider is assigned to the linewidth, however changing the slider won't cause a change to the value of linewidth.

html:

```
<input type="range" name="brushsize" min="0" max="20" id="brushSlider" step="1" value="5" onchange="this.setAttribute('value',this.value);">
```

js:

```
var brushSize = document.getElementById("brushSlider").value; 
context.lineWidth = brushSize;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The linewidth value is not changing because you are only setting it once. You need to set an event listener on the input to update the linewidth when the input has been changed.

```
var brushSlider = document.getElementById("brushSlider"); 
context.lineWidth = brushSlider.value;

brushSlider.addEventListener("change", function () {
    context.lineWidth = brushSlider.value;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="range" name="brushsize" min="0" max="20"
 id="brushSlider" step="1" value="5" onchange="changeLineWidth(this.value);">

function changeLineWidth(brushSize){
   context.lineWidth = brushSize;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but didn't work. The linewidth would not change.

Comment: yeah you are right, I missed the argument and assignment.. corrected now.

Comment: But I would recommend to go with approach that of accepted answer from @Chris. I have given this answer so you could understand what was wrong with the code.